# TextIO. Read multiple files from GCS using pattern {}

Tags: google-cloud-storage, glob, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I tried using the following

```
TextIO.Read.from("gs://xyz.abc/xxx_{2017-06-06,2017-06-06}.csv")
```

That pattern didn't work, as I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find any files matching StaticValueProvider{value=gs://xyz.abc/xxx_{2017-06-06,2017-06-06}.csv}
```

Even though those 2 files do exist. And I tried with a local file using a similar expression

```
TextIO.Read.from("somefolder/xxx_{2017-06-06,2017-06-06}.csv")
```

And that did work just fine.

I would've thought there would be support for all kinds of globs for files in GCS, but nope. Why is that? is there away to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Docs say it supports "Standard Java Filesystem globbing" but it appears to only support these `* matches everything` , `?  matches any single character` , `[seq]   matches any character in seq` ,  `[!seq]  matches any char not in seq`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may be another option, in addition to Scott's suggestion and your comment on his answer:

You can define a list with the paths you want to read and then iterate over it, creating a number of PCollections in the usual way:

```
PCollection<String> events1 = p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(path1));
PCollection<String> events2 = p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(path2));
```

Then create a **PCollectionList**:

```
PCollectionList<String> eventsList = PCollectionList.of(events1).and(events2);
```

And then **flatten** this list into your PCollection for your main input:

`PCollection<String> events = eventsList.apply(Flatten.pCollections());`

Answer (score 3):

Glob patterns work slightly differently in Google Cloud Storage vs. the local filesystem. Apache Beam's `TextIO.Read` transform will defer to the underlying filesystem to interpret the glob.

GCS glob wildcard patterns are documented [here (Wildcard Names)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames).

In the case above, you could use:

```
TextIO.Read.from("gs://xyz.abc/xxx_2017-06-*.csv")
```

Note however that this will also include any other matching files.

Comment: I'm thinking about passing the list of files to a ParDo instead, but I have no idea on how to do it :P

Comment: See @Matthias Baetens' great solution to read the two files separately and then merge them with `Flatten.pCollections`.

Answer (score -4):

Did you try Apache Beam `TextIO.Read from` function? [Here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Read.html#from-java.lang.String-), it says that it is possible with gcs as well:

`public TextIO.Read from(java.lang.String filepattern)`

`Reads text files that reads from the file(s) with the given filename or filename pattern. This can be a local path (if running locally), or a Google Cloud Storage filename or filename pattern of the form "gs://<bucket>/<filepath>" (if running locally or using remote execution service).`

`Standard Java Filesystem glob patterns ("*", "?", "[..]") are supported.`

Comment: that's what I'm using.