# Google Dataflow - Create one PCollection<TableRow> from multiple PCollection< TableRow >

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have 2 TableRow PCollection -

1. PCollection validRow : This TableRow contains (key1 , valiue1)
2. PCollection inValidRow : This TableRow contains (key2, valiue2)

From the above PCollection , I want to create one PCollection tableRow containing  both keyvalue pairs  ((key1 , valiue1) , (key2 , value2))

Comment: Are you looking to concatenate the two PCollections, or to join them together?

Comment: I want to concatenate two PCollection<TableRow>.  As both PCollection contains different keys. I want to create one PCollection<TableRow> having key1, key2 keys and want to save in the bigquery table.

Comment: My question is If you want to write these pcollection's in BQ table then you can write these pcollection separately into bigquery. why you want to join these in one pcollection?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my answer to a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407323/textio-read-multiple-files-from-gcs-using-pattern/44431962#44431962).
You will want to create a PCollectionList and then flatten it:

```
PCollection<TableRow> validRow = ...
PCollection<TableRow> inValidRow = ...

PCollectionList<TableRow> rowList = PCollectionList.of(validRow).and(inValidRow);

PCollection<TableRow> rows = rowList.apply(Flatten.pCollections());
```

Comment: Hi Matthias,   
I want to create only one PCollection<TableRow> row from input 2 different PCollection<TableRow>. Once i get one TableRow [(key1,value1), (key2,value2)] , i will save  that row into BQ table as one row having fileds (key1, key2 )

Comment: That's exactly what the above code does. You have 2 `PCollection`s of TableRows (validRow and inValidRow) and combine this into one PCollection of TableRows that you can write to BigQuery. You are still confusing me about joining and concatenating though, because the above explanation sounds like you want to join, while previously you said you wanted to concatenate.

Comment: Baji, do you want a single element in the entire collection? If not, how are you decide which rows should be combined?